# The browser console doesn't recognize js vars that were injected with selenium webdriver

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I try to bowser to a page with selenium web-driver.

I then inject and execute some js via selenium web-driver.

I try to access these vars in this opened browser console,
but it seems they were not created. How come?

I have this code:

```
public void foo (){
        String script =
                "var aLocation = {};" +
                        "var aOffer = {};" +

                        "var aAdData = " +
                        "{ " +
                        "location:  aLocation, " +
                        "offer:    aOffer " +
                        " };" +

                        "var aClientEnv = " +
                        " { " +
                        "    sessionid:     \"\", " +
                        "   cookie:        \"\", " +
                        "       lon:           34.847, " +
                        "       lat:           32.123, " +
                        "       venue:         \"\", " +
                        "    venue_context: \"\", " +

                        "    source:        \"\"," +   // One of the following (string) values: ADS_PIN_INFO,
                        // ADS_0SPEED_INFO, ADS_LINE_SEARCH_INFO,
                        // ADS_ARROW_NEARBY_INFO, ADS_CATEGORY_AUTOCOMPLETE_INFO,
                        // ADS_HISTORY_LIST_INFO
                        // (this field is also called "channel")

                        "    locale:        \"\"" + // ISO639-1 language code (2-5 characters), supported formats:
                        " };" +


                        "W.setOffer(aAdData, aClientEnv);";

            javascriptExecutor.executeScript(script);
}
```

which yields:

`script = 
var aLocation = {};
var aOffer = {};
var aAdData = {
    location: aLocation,
    offer: aOffer
};
var aClientEnv = {
    sessionid: "",
    cookie: "",
    rtserver - id: 1,
    lon: 34.847,
    lat: 32.123,
    venue: "",
    venue_context: "",
    source: "",
    locale: ""
};
W.setOffer(aAdData, aClientEnv);`

I evaluate `aLocation` in this browser console and get `"variable not defined"`. How can this be?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your variables are NOT `global`. As soon as you declare them with `var` they are scoped. If you want to test something out, just put `nemo=100;` in your script above and try printing out in console, it should work.

Edit #1
By the way, by no means I'm advocating global variables here. I'm just trying to explain what happened to your variables in JS executed by WebDriver. If you want to use global variables then more explicit declaration like `window.foo` makes more sense like others have suggested. However overall try to avoid using them. Moreover try to avoid executing JavaScript using WebDriver in the first place 
unless you have no other choice. WebDriver is supposed to simulate a real user for you and your user is less likely to execute a JavaScript to interact with your web app.

Answer (score 3):

It is important to know how Selenium executes the JavaScript that is executed in the browser.

Contrarily to what [nilesh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28458065/1906307) implies slapping a `var` in front of a variable declaration does not take it out of the global space. For instance if `var foo = 1` is executed outside of a function scope, it will declare a global variable named `foo`.

The key is how Selenium executes the script. It would be *possible* for Selenium to execute the script passed to `executeScript` in the global space. (There are ways.) However, it does not. What it does is wrap the script in a new function so any `var` that appears in the code passed to `executeScript` is going to declare a local variable.

Just dropping the `var` would work but I prefer to be explicit when I want to manipulate the global space. I explicitly access the `window` object (e.g. `window.foo = 1`). Dropping `var` looks like it could be a mistake, whereas using `window.` looks deliberate.

Comment: My answer doesn't suggest to use global variable that way at all. It just answers OP question on what happened to his variables. Also If I understand you right your second and fourth paragraphs are contradictory. Declaring var foo doesn't declare global variable foo

Comment: You did not understand my answer.

Comment: quite possible. I didn't understand this part "For instance if var foo = 1 is executed outside of a function scope, it will declare a global variable named foo."

Comment: Put that statement in a `<script>` tag, load it, and then check the value of `window.foo`. It will be 1. The `var` statement determines whether a variable is going to be global *only* if it is inside a function's scope. Outside a function's scope, `var` or no `var`, the variable will be global.

Comment: I see, I get that. But that's not in selenium context, you are talking in JS context. In selenium, you have only access to `driver.executeScript`

Comment: As I said in my answer `executeScript` *could* execute the code to get the same effect as putting the code in a `<script>` tag ("execute the script [...] in the global space"), in which case the OP here would have gotten the expected results, but it does not. The key is that it wraps the code passed to it in a function. It does not *have* to do this but it does.