# Using Selenium WebDriver JavascriptExecutor to manipulate one JS variable in separate scripts

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I need to reach the following scenario:

1) Initializing JS var with JavascriptExecutor that will indicate if some operation is done.

2) Do some ordinary manipulation with the renderer page.

3) Verify the change to the var created in point (1).

For example:

```
jsc.executeScript("var test = false;");
```

Now, some manipulation is done.
And then:

```
String testVal = jsc.executeScript("return test;").toString
```

I get the error:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: {"errorMessage":"Can't find
>   variable: test","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json,
>   image/png","Connection":"Keep-Alive","Content-Length":"35","Content-Type":"application/json;
>   charset=utf-8","Host":"localhost:14025"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"args\":[],\"script\":\"return
>   test;\"}","url":"/execute","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"execute","directory":"/","path":"/execute","relative":"/execute","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/execute","queryKey":{},"chunks":["execute"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/7e2c8ab0-b781-11e4-8a54-6115c321d700/execute"}}

When i'm running them in the same execution, it works correctly.:

```
   String testVal = jsc.executeScript("var test = false; return test;").toString;
```

From [JavascriptExecutor doc](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html) i found the explanation i needed:

> Within the script, use document to refer to the current document. Note
>   that local variables will not be available once the script has
>   finished executing, though global variables will persist.

What is my alternative/workaround to this?

Comment: Upvote for an interesting question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The browser console doesn't recognize js vars that were injected with selenium webdriver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28457571/the-browser-console-doesnt-recognize-js-vars-that-were-injected-with-selenium-w)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what is the motivation behind it, but you can use a globally available `window` object:

```
jsc.executeScript("window.test = false;");
String testVal = jsc.executeScript("return window.test;").toString
```

It might also be a use case for `executeAsyncSript()`, see:

- [Understanding execute async script in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28057338/understanding-execute-async-script-in-selenium)

Comment: @alecxe So, `window.test = false;` registers `test` variable against current `driver`?

Comment: @Saifur I think it is in the "scope" of the current browser window - hence, basically, you can say that it in the scope of the current webdriver session.